# Unity reflect bullets off wall at a constant speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2.5D tank game where the rocket that comes out of the tank bounces off of walls. The rocket currently gets reflected back off of walls at the right angle, however it looses speed on impact.

How can I make the rocket object maintain a constant speed after hitting off a wall?
I want to be able to change this set speed while the game is running.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the rocket/wall components, including any physics materials they might have? I assume you're using the physics system to handle the reflections rather than scripting it yourself - but if you have relevant code please include that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a rigidbody, or if you want there to be no way to interact with the object via physics, then simply do:

```
transform.position += constantVelocity * Time.deltaTime;
```

in `LateUpdate` or `Update`.

where constantVelocity is a Vector3 containing the desired change in position per second.

[Source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/170362/keep-constant-velocity.html)